# Report processing has been canceled by the user. (rsProcessingAborted)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am getting below error message while run reports from SSRS server.

Report processing has been canceled by the user. (rsProcessingAborted)

In the SSRS report i am calling the SP and provided the same user permission to the SP(same used in the datasource) but i am getting rsProcessingAborted error message.

Please help me if anyone have idea about the issue

Already tried below things:
- Updated dataset query time out to 1000 seconds
- updated the SSRS site setting query execution timeout to 1000 seconds.

Comment: Can't really say for sure, but SSRS is rather dumb in terms of errors.  I'd recommend double checking any expressions you have to make sure everything works correctly.  I'd also verify that the parameters on your report, datasource, and dataset match the parameters on the proc.  Additionally, you could refresh the fields in your dataset to verify that your proc hasn't changed.

Comment: Is there anything logged in the server's eventviewer?

Comment: How long does it run before it gives the error message? Are you able to see the command is executing against the datasource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added system database(tempdb, msdb, master, modal) mapping to the SSRS user.

Because i am creating the temp table inside the SP so we need the SSRS user permission to store temporary table in temp db and also require msdb.

After changing above things it's working good.

Thanks Guys for your comments.